# Multi-line strings NASM

Tags: string, nasm

I feel like this is a dumb question, but somehow I can't find the answer. I just want a multi-line string (kind of like `"""this"""` in Python) in NASM. I feel stupid for asking this.

Thanks.

Comment: NASM doesn't have those yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NASM doesnt support multi-line strings, but you can do this to make your strings cleaner:

```
; instead of this:
string1: db "Hello", 0xA, "World", 0xA, "!!!!!", 0xA, 0

; you can define the lines separately 
; don't forget 0xA from the end of the line
string2: db "Hello", 0xA
         db "World", 0xA
         db "!!!!!", 0xA, 0
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: As it happens, @Berc07 this is perfect. +1.